# Fixed Jumbotron Image - Columns Overflow?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I finally figured out how to make the jumbotron image fit the entire width and HEIGHT of a user's browser:

```css
.jumbotron {
    background: url(images/yelllow.png) no-repeat center;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Now, when I add another section `div class = row`, the columns to not show up underneath the jumbotron image. Instead, they show up on the top of the page and overlap the jumbotron text. JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/srLngrsx/

I isolated each CSS property above and found out that `position: fixed` is causing this to happen. When I remove `position: fixed` the columns line up underneath like they should, but the jumbotron image is now a smaller size, not fitting to the screen.

Can anybody identify or explain why exactly `position: fixed` is causing the other elements to not position properly? How can I make it so the jumbotron header fits the width AND HEIGHT of the page, and the rest of the content shows up below?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>test</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmo</p>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h3>Column 1</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
                <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h3>Column 2</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
                <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h3>Column 3</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
                <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
.jumbotron {
    background: url(images/yelllow.png) no-repeat center;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/srLngrsx/3/

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. thanks for introducing me to vh. i took away the top: 0 and left:0 and it still has the same effect - is there any reason to keep that in there?

Answer (score 0):

Move your jumbotron in the container and give it a row and full-width column.

http://jsfiddle.net/srLngrsx/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>test</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmo</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>Column 1</h3>
            ...
```

Comment: sorry for not including this earlier, but I meant to want the jumbotron to fit both the height and width of the browser window.

Comment: You can give the jumbotron a container of it's own but use a container-fluid which uses 100% browser width whereas container is 100% parent width.  http://jsfiddle.net/srLngrsx/2/

Comment: My answer shouldn't make the image full browser size, I think you meant this on vanburenx's post.  For mine, you can also try to add bootstrap's img-responsive class to your image so that it resizes properly.

Answer (score 0):

when you use position:fixed for any element , you have to use margin-top for the elements after it . in this example you have to use margin-top for the class row . because the elements after the fixed positioned element will start from the top position of the fixed element.

```
.jumbotron {
    background: url(images/yelllow.png) no-repeat center;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.row {
    margin-top:300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/srLngrsx/4/